# Get data from a website and store some images and text both in one variable?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project which grabs some data from a webpage using python BeautifulSoup library. Suppose there's a answer on Quora and I want to store it locally in my python variable. The answer may contain images and text, so how can I store them in a single variable?

I have tried to get the Question Name, Author Name and some more but the problem lies with the answer.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print("\nLoading Data..")
result = requests.get("https://qr.ae/TWGJU0")

success = result.status_code
if success==200:
    print("Connection to the webpage was successful..!\n")

src = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

question = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'question_link'})
print("Question:"+question.text)

author = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'user'})
print("Author:"+author.text)

profile = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'user'})
print("Author Profile: https://www.quora.com"+profile.attrs['href'])

print("\n")
answer = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'u-serif-font-main--regular'})
print("Answer:"+answer.text)
```

The output only prints the text data, I know that it is beacuse I have used 'answer.text', but still how can I make this work?

Comment: check for `answer.select('img')`

Comment: @SmartManoj can you please explain in detail

Comment: It returns a  list of all the images in the answer

Comment: there are no images in this example's answer. Do you mean you want the images from the comments?

Comment: @chitown88 check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the images stored as a variable, just pull the `<img>` tags. It is possible there are multiple images, so it can be stored in a list by using list comprehension:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print("\nLoading Data..")
result = requests.get("https://qr.ae/TWGJU0")

success = result.status_code
if success==200:
    print("Connection to the webpage was successful..!\n")

src = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

question = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'question_link'})
print("Question:"+question.text)

author = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'user'})
print("Author:"+author.text)

profile = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'user'})
print("Author Profile: https://www.quora.com"+profile.attrs['href'])

print("\n")
answer = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'u-serif-font-main--regular'})
print("Answer:"+answer.text)

print("\n")
images = [ each['src'] for each in answer.find_all('img') ]
for image in images:
    print ("Images:" + image)
```

Now your images are stored in a single variable:

```
print (images)
['https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-1034d14bf757fcbedc38dfdb186413d3']
```

**Or**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print("\nLoading Data..")
result = requests.get("https://qr.ae/TWGJU0")

success = result.status_code
if success==200:
    print("Connection to the webpage was successful..!\n")

src = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

question = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'question_link'})
print("Question:"+question.text)

author = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'user'})
print("Author:"+author.text)

profile = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'user'})
print("Author Profile: https://www.quora.com"+profile.attrs['href'])

print("\n")
answer = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'u-serif-font-main--regular'})


answer_images = []
for sentence in answer.find_all():
    if sentence.name == 'p':
        answer_images.append(sentence.text)
    if sentence.name == 'img':
        answer_images.append(sentence['src'])

answer = ' '.join(answer_images)

print("Answer:"+answer)
```

If you're looking to store that answer with the image within the answer, you can iterate through those elements. It won't display the image though unless you do some more manipulation like save it as html, or convert the url to an image in some way using `cv2`, or matplot, or some other package to display the image:

**Another way:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

print("\nLoading Data..")
result = requests.get("https://qr.ae/TWGJU0")

success = result.status_code
if success==200:
    print("Connection to the webpage was successful..!\n")

src = result.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

question = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'question_link'})
print("Question:"+question.text)

author = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'user'})
print("Author:"+author.text)

profile = soup.find("a", attrs={'class': 'user'})
print("Author Profile: https://www.quora.com"+profile.attrs['href'])

print("\n")
answer = soup.find("div", attrs={'class':'u-serif-font-main--regular'})


answer_images = []
for sentence in answer.find_all():
    if sentence.name == 'p':
        answer_images.append(sentence.text)
    if sentence.name == 'img':
        answer_images.append(sentence['src'])

for each in answer_images:
    if 'https://' in each:
        a = plt.imread('https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-1034d14bf757fcbedc38dfdb186413d3')
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.imshow(a)
        plt.show()
    else:
        print (each + ' ')
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks @chitown88.. i actually needed a different answer but this is also very helpful, now I can use it as per my need

Comment: exactly. Just needed an example where an image would be there to work with it

Comment: i have a issue.. the image and text is printed differently, whats the matter

Comment: and only the above image is displayed... what should i replace the image link in the loop